# Where does number==int(number) fails to classify the number variable as integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know about isinstance(), but I was just curious as to why we don't use:
number==int(number).

Comment: In many cases, because a `False` is more useful than a `ValueError` or `TypeError`.

Comment: Because `int(..)` converts something to an `int`. Furthermore since the `==` can be overloaded, that means that it is possible for non-int's to match that.

Comment: A simple counter example: the type of `14.00` is `float`, but `number == int(number)` will work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short**: the two do completely different things: it is possible that the check will return `True` if something is not an `int`, it will raise `ValueError`s or `TypeError`s for a lot of types you aim to convert to an `int`, and it is even sometimes possible that the above will return `False`.

The `isinstance(..)` method furthermore makes it clear *what* you are doing, and is more convenient as well. For example, you can check if something is an `int` *or* a `float` with `isinstance(1.0, (int, float))`.

---

## Case 1: return `True` for non-`int`s

Because it is *not* guaranteed that this will only return `True` for `int`egers, and it might even raise errors.

A simple counter example is `1.0`. This is a float:

```
>>> number = 1.0
>>> type(number)
<class 'float'>
>>> number == int(number)
True
```

Because the equality check can check if the value of a `float` with `1.0` has the same value as an `int` that has value `1`, this check thus fails.

## Case 2: raise a `ValueError`

Another problem is that not everything can be converted to an `int`. Take for example the string `'foo'`:

```
>>> int('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

This gives a `ValueError`, since `'foo'` makes no sense when we want to convert it to an `int`.

## Case 3: raise a `TypeError`

Not all classes implement an `__int__` function, the function that is called behind the curtains to convert to an `int`. For example a simple object has no such function. In that case, it will raise a type error:

```
>>> int(object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'object'
```

## Case 4: return `False` for subclasses of `int`

Finally if you subclass `int`, it is possible that during the conversion to an `int`, data is lost, and thus the two are not considered equal, whereas, due to being a subclass of `int`, the `isinstance(..)` call would have succeeded. Take for example the following "strange" class:

```
class Foo(int):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Foo)

    def __int__(self):
        return self
```

Then if we check the above, we see:

```
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo == int(foo)
False
>>> isinstance(foo, int)
True
```